# How to get the UWP user identity across devices

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I have been using and hating the Roaming feature for a while now. For my use case, it's just not reliable enough and the storage is somewhat limited too.

I'm going to implement my own custom syncing storage and system, but i would like to avoid users creating an account specifically for my app.

Is there some way of retrieving a user unique identifier, related to the MS account, that will be the same across all the user devices ?
For instance, if the user has a Laptop and a Surface using the same MS account, the  ID returned should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the [`WebAccountManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-account-manager); you could ask for a Microsoft Account or Facebook etc.

You should allocate your own unique ID (eg, a GUID) and then associate it with the user ID you get from the broker so you can do things like migrate accounts to different providers over time.

Comment: I was hoping something with less UI (kind of how the in-app purchases are common on all devices without you requiring to log in anything but the Store app) but yes it would work. I'll accept it as an answer in a few days if no one has a better idea.

Comment: There needs to be some UI so the user has a chance to give consent. Creating an ID and storing it in your roaming folder is the easiest but you said that wasn't working well for you. (The data will eventually age out if the use uninstalls the app(.